# second scene in sprite kit changes position (anchor point)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

When i click the `playButton` from my `MenuScene` to change to the `GameScene` it works fine. Only every node, sprite,... changes from position in my `GameScene`. It's like the anchorpoint changes form (0,5 ; 0,5) to (0,0). I don't know where or what to change. In my .sks files both anchor points in the attributes inspector are the same.

This is the code where i change from the `MenuScene` to the `GameScene`:
This is written in the `MenuScene`:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

  let touch = touches.first

    if let location = touch?.location(in: self) {
        let nodeArray = self.nodes(at: location)

        if nodeArray.first?.name == "playButton" {
            let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
            gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `GameScene(size: self.size)` means you are creating a default GameScene object at the size of the previous scene.  Avoid using this initializer at almost all cost.  Instead do`GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")` and set your `scaleMode` from the old scene to this one

Comment: I changed it to `GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")` but then i get this error: Cannot convert value of type 'GameScene.Type' to expected argument type 'String'... and hat do you mean by 'old scene'?

Comment: You typo-ed something, I am assuming you forgot the quotes for `"GameScene"`  As for old scene..... you are transitioning to a new scene from an old scene, as of right now `self` is your old/current scene

Comment: ... I just forgot it needs to be a string and forgot my quotes... Thanks a million!!